# How to turn off ubuntu completely?

Tags: kde, shutdown, 20.04, plasma

I have ubuntu 20.04 with kde plasma, how do I turn it off completely? Even reisub saves applications when it's turned off.

Comment: Hello and welcome to askubuntu. It is not clear what you mean by turn off completely. Shutdown turns off ubuntu completely. reisub does not save applications, it sends the SIGTERM signal allowing applications to terminate gracefully. This involves saving some data so that they can be restarted later...If you want to skip this step just type risub. Though I really think, you should explain your problem clearer.

Comment: I get the "baloo file extractor closed unexpectedly" error and I am sure that a normal full reboot will solve my problem, but I already doubt it.

Comment: A first step would be to disable baloo if you do not need it. Run `balooctl disable`. A full reboot can be achieved by `shutdown -r now`. There is no reason why a reboot in itself should solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Terrorka and welcome to AskUbuntu. I agree with @Bruni, your question is not clear enough and for me it is difficult to understand what you want to do or what is the problem you are having. From the question, it seems that you want to shutdown the system, but by you comment I understand that you are having a problem with "baloo"

Comment: As much as it looks like a "baloo" I do not need in principle, but it was he who made me think that ubuntu 20.04 my first linux, which can not fully turn off. Even after rebooting kde plasma cheerfully meets me with fanfares and running applications like explorer and settings.

Comment: If you go to settings --> startup and shutdown --> Desktop session you can decide for yourself if you want KDE to restore the previous session or start with an empty session on login.

Comment: Thank you, @Bruni. Please duplicate this as an answer.

Comment: Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, please do not add "SOLVED" to the title. Correct way to do it is by accepting an helpful answer (which you already did).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to settings --> startup and shutdown --> Desktop session you can decide for yourself if you want KDE to restore the previous session or start with an empty session on login